# Prevent very permissive object type from matching any function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create type definitions for a JavaScript library which is pretty permissive with its schemas.
In particular, I've come across a situation where a type can either be a function or an object which has a `handler` property being the function instead:

```
type SpecificFunc = (arg: string) => number;

type VeryPermissiveObject = {
    name?: string;
    type?: number;
    handler?: SpecificFunc;

    [key: string]: any;
}
```

This is a minimalist example but it is faithful to the situation. As you can see, `VeryPermissiveObject` is **very** permissive and can accept any key of any type (except `name`, `type` and `handler` which have specific types.)

Inside the JavaScript code, the test is easy and it looks like so:

```js
if (typeof objOrFunc === "function") {
  // Do something
}
```

Now, I did an union of both of those types:

```
type OneOfThem = SpecificFunc | VeryPermissiveObject;
```

and tried to use it:

```
// I would like test1 to report an error stating that parameter 'arg' of type `number` is not assignable to `string`
const test1: OneOfThem = (arg: number) => { return "" };
```

As you can see, the function `test1` does not satisfy the type of `SpecificFunc` but it's still accepted by TypeScript because it matches `VeryPermissiveObject`.

[Playground Link of this toy example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAZo+AxArgO3lAvFABQCGATgOYBcUAzsGYthQJQEB8U2mAtgEYQyAbgCwAKHGhIUAGqCQABUE9EtWogBuEAPJ8AVhHjACUAN7iolriR4QA-DXqNmosVahT7Nbv0Gv3ABYk2AAmADaCDrAIKGhYuK4WVgDaANYQII4MTBQAujTBIK4AvuKS4NDa2DrIACoBEDwmcIaxGDh4AD6y8kpkKmqaOvqGwIliAPQTUACSUADuAPaYYSFQYYjpHhD0AIwei1BkEGCLZMbBUIJkZ3TAJMA5HkHGYOQ2EMCCUADk5BQ-KCLZAeCpQAAGPgEZHBUFUXEWF0GFGwJD4EQOEKcOXB4ngi2w9G2exoVRq9UaJlIlG8vGhbHwnFMR0+mDI2CgACJOVBiq4gA)

I would like to know if there is a way to slightly alter this situation so that TypeScript is not allowed to match a function against `VeryPermissiveObject`.

Comment: Maybe start with something like `type OneOfThem<T> = (
    (arg: string) => number
    | T extends Function ? never : {
        name?: string;`, but that doesn't quite work, it needs some tweaking. All `VeryPermissiveObject` keys are optional, and a function is a type of object, so your incorrect function passes with your current code.

Comment: I've gotten to the point where I can use a utility type to check if an individual type is valid.  But I don't know how to get a union of every possibility that passes the check. `type IfOk<T, OnTrue = T, OnFalse = never> = T extends Function ? 
    T extends SpecificFunc ? OnTrue : OnFalse : 
    T extends VeryPermissiveObject ? OnTrue : OnFalse;`

Comment: I'm not sure I can use a generic type for `OneOfThem` since I need it to be automatically deduced based on the assignation